# "Optional" object file target in Makefile?

Tags: c++, makefile

I have some code that is "optional": the rest of the program can be linked without it.
How do I properly create a Makefile that excludes it as a dependency if there is an error when creating the object file?

So far I have something like this:

```
OUT=my_program
OBJS=$(subst .cc,.o,$(wildcard *.cc))

all: $(OUT)
$(OUT): $(OBJS)

my_optional_file.o: other_target

.IGNORE: my_optional_file.o
```

The good: When processing the rule `my_optional_file.o`, this correctly ignores all errors.

The bad: When linking the output, `my_optional_file.o` is specified as an argument to the linker *despite the fact* that it was not built, making the linker fail because it was given a nonexistent file as input!

How do I exclude `my_optional_file.o` when there is an error in building it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$(shell find . -maxdepth 1 -iname "*.o")` with an explicit call to the linker.

Like :

```
$(OUT): $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $(shell find . -maxdepth 1 -iname "*.o") $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

The reason is that when implicitly called, the linker command is called like this :

```
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

With `$^` expanding to the content of `$(OBJS)`. You need an explicit call to use specific files instead.

---

The `$(wildcard *.o)` function cannot be used because it is executed before the files are created so it is always empty.

Comment: I'm not calling the linker manually at all, I think it's called implicitly. Should I be?

Comment: It is not called implicitly here.

Comment: I know *you're* not calling it implicitly, what I'm saying is I definitely don't have an explicit call in my Makefile yet it is still being called. Are you saying that shouldn't be happening?

Comment: Since the Makefile you've posted isn't the complete one you're using I guess, I can only tell for what you've provided. In this particular setup, it isn't called implicitly when using `make`. __See my edit.__

Comment: +1 you led me to the right answer. I didn't realize calling the linker explicitly works so well. It works pretty fine now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `make` is GNU `make`, here is one way of doing this.

Say my program `prog` has three source files `main.c`, `necessary.c`, `optional.c`
such that I want to link `prog` from all three `.o` files, if they get
built ( = a *maximal build*), but I will settle for `main.o` and `necessary.o` ( = a *minimal build*). (I waive the rationale for this).

A makefile to the purpose is:

```
.phony: all clean make_prog

max_objs=$(subst .c,.o,$(wildcard *.c))

all: make_prog

make_prog: $(max_objs)
    $(MAKE) prog

prog: $(wildcard *.o)
    gcc -o $@ $^

clean:
    rm -f prog *.o

.IGNORE: optional.o
```

To make `prog` I first make the phony target, `make_prog`, whose
prerequisites are all three `.o` files, but I ignore failure to make
`optional.o`. Then I make `prog` for real, and to do that I just
link whatever `.o` files I've got at this point. If `optional.o`
isn't there, it doesn't matter.

To be clear about the behaviour of this:-

- If, initially, I have a maximal build of `prog`, then make a change that breaks
  `optional.c` and re-make, no `.o` is re-made, so `prog` is not re-made. It
  stays maximal.
- If, initially, I have a minimal build of `prog`, then make a change that *fixes*
  `optional.c` and re-make, `optional.o` is re-made, so `prog` is re-made. It
  becomes maximal.

Failure to make `optional.o` excludes `prog`'s dependency on it and introduces
no new ones. So if all other dependencies are satisfied, there's no need to
remake `prog`.

Now it might be the case that you actually want failure to make `optional.o` to
introduce a dependency on *the failure to make* `optional.o`, in the
sense that it would force `prog` to be rebuilt *minimally*.

A simple way to achieve that is by adding the line:

```
.INTERMEDIATE: optional.o
```

to the makefile,  which will force `optional.o` always to be deleted at the end of a make.
This has the cost that `optional.c` will always be compiled, and consequently a *maximal* build will always be re-linked.

Lastly, someone might wonder why the makefile couldn't more simply be:

```
.phony: all clean

objs=$(subst .c,.o,$(wildcard *.c))

all: prog

prog: $(objs)
    gcc -o $@ $(wildcard *.o)

clean:
    rm -f prog *.o

.IGNORE: optional.o
```

Well if we do a make from clean with that, the output is:

```
cc    -c -o main.o main.c
cc    -c -o necessary.o necessary.c
cc    -c -o optional.o optional.c
gcc -o prog 
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
make: *** [prog] Error 4
```

That's because `$(wildcard *.o)` is expanded when the makefile is
parsed, and at that point no `.o` files exist. We need to be parsing
the makefile *again* when we expand this, having already made all
the `.o` files we can.

Comment: +1, but *"This has the cost that `optional.c` will always be compiled"*... is there no way to avoid this? I actually ran into this problem when trying this route but wasn't sure how to fix it...

Answer (score 0):

GNU make does not have optional dependencies. You can simulate that by not returning failure when it fails to build and filtering out non-existent objects when linking.